Dividing 4 individual numbers.
So obviously dividing (3/4)/(3/4) would be the same as (3/4) x (4/3) which is 1. Or dividing 3/5/5 would be like doing 3/5 x 1/5 which is 3/25. But, what if you have four individual numbers what's the rule to divide those? Ie: 4/5/5/4 cannot use the reciprocal rule like in both cases above or it would be 16/25. But, from what I see in the calculator you are simply multiplying, so how does that work?

As you remark, the notation $a/b/c/d$ is hard to parse.  So, don't use that notation.  Non associative operations are a mess.

Please add parentheses to $4/5/5/4$, like you did with $(3/4)/(3/4)$.

If you (or your calculator) are reading 3/5/5 left-to-right as $(3/5)/5$ then you or it may read  4/5/5/4 as $((4/5)/5)/4$.  This is  a common convention in the same way that it is common to read 4-5-5-4 as $((4-5)-5)-4$.  Though remember that a common convention for exponentiation is  to read 4^5^5^4 right-to-left as in $4_{,}^{\left(5^{\left(5^4\right)}\right)}$

Division is not associative.  You need to clarify what order you are dividing by including parenthesis.  Otherwise.... it's ambiguous and it's impossible to know what you want to do.  In short; you divide them in the order you need to divide them in and you clarify it by saying specifically what you need to say.  (Actually "dividing $3/5/5$ is not clear  Are doing $(3/5)/5 =\frac 35 \times \frac 15=\frac 3{25}$ or are you doing $3/(5/5) = \frac 3{(\frac 55)}=\frac 31 = 3$?)

One problem with teaching PEDMAS (or whatever other shortcut the teach-- In my day we didn't use these shortcuts and ... well, we got just as confused as anyone else did) is that it gives the false impression if you express something ambiguous there is some magical judge who says one think is right or the other is.  $2/3/4/5$ is utterly ambiguous and there is no way we can determine if you mean: $\frac 2{\frac 3{\frac 45}}$ or $\frac 2{\frac {\frac 34}5}$ or $\frac{\frac 2{\frac 34}}5$ or $\frac 2{\frac{\frac 34}5}$ or $\frac {\frac 23}{\frac 45}$ or $\frac 2{\frac 3{\frac 45}}$ or what..

I believe that you are confusing yourself because of your lack of parentheses. If it is (4/5)/(5/4) you can use the reciprocal rule as you thought but when you typed it into a calculator, the calculator thought you meant (((4/5)/5)/4) which would mean that you are repeatedly multiplying by the reciprocal essentially taking the last three numbers and multiplying to get the denominator.
